# Is it enough to use "#pragma inline" on function prototype with the IAR compiler?

Tags: c, pragma, iar

I do no use IAR myself and I can't test it myself (otherwise I would not ask this question here).

My question is: Is it enough to apply `#pragma inline=xxxxx` on the function prototype (as it is possible using the `__attribute__` in gcc) and have definition somewhere in the file without this `#pragma`

gcc example:

```
static inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) foo(int x);

/* .... */

static inline int foo(int x)
{
    return x + x;
}
```

I'd like to have the same using the `#pragma inline=...` when compiling using IAR compiler.

```
#pragma inline=forced
static inline int foo(int x);

/* .... */

static inline int foo(int x)
{
    return x + x;
}
```

My question is: *Will it work in IAR?*

Comment: If you don't use IAR and cannot test it, why do you want to know? If it is for someone else, why don't you ask that person? What does IAR's documentation say?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this will work. The compiler will recognize that `foo()` is a forced-inline function if you apply `#pragma inline=forced` on the function prototype.